# In Firebase Cloud Messaging, where can I see the list of users/devices who have registered for push?

Tags: firebase, firebase-cloud-messaging

I’m testing Firebase Cloud Messaging with iOS.

Every time I send out a test notification to the app on my iPhone, the number in the screenshot increases, even if it’s the same device.

Anyone know where I can see this list of users? Would preferrably like to manage these, force remove them etc.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The tooltip says `Estimate based on approximately xxxx users who are registered to receive notifications. Some targeted users will not see the message due to device inactivity. For recurring campaigns, estimate is for initial send only.`
I don't believe you can see that list of registered users anywhere.